# Javascript - find the index of clicked button

Tags: javascript

I have N buttons on the page, and I need to find which button is clicked. So far I have this code, which will show the number of buttons, instead of button order:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rapqsa7r/16/)

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
   nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('You clicked element #' + );

   });
}
```

Comment: console.log('You clicked element #' + node[i]); this should work i believe

Comment: No that wont work, @redsecurity

Comment: Oh sorry just put i not node[i]

Comment: That wont work either, @redsecurity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a closure or use `bind`, since the value of `i` will have already reached the final value before you actually click and before the click handler looks up the value of `i`:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
   nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(i) {
      console.log('You clicked element #' + i);
   }.bind(null, i));
}
```

`bind` will create a copy of the function that has the current value of `i` bound to it, so it does no harm if `i` changes by the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't now if I understand your question, but is this resolve your question?

```
  var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  for (var i = 0, size = nodes.length; i < size; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(i) {
      console.log('You clicked element index' + i);
    }.bind(null, i));
  }
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/podicumeha/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
   nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(index) {
      console.log('You clicked element index' + index);
   }.bind(this, i));
}
```